# Empty atom in Ecto changeset

Tags: elixir, ecto

Why in an Ecto `changeset` method do you set the params to the default `:empty` atom?  e.g.

```
def changeset(user, params \\ :empty) do
   ...
```

Does this allow you to call the changeset method with nil for params?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is explained in Programming Phoenix:

> **Chris says:** If there are no parameters specified, we can’t just default to an empty map because that would be indistinguishable from a blank form submission. Instead, we default params to the atom :empty. By convention, Ecto will produce an invalid changeset, with empty parameters.

So `:empty` is used as a placeholder so that we can distinguish between a blank form submission and no parameters specified.

---

As [Stefan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278817/stefan) notes in the comment below:

> Note that with Ecto 2.0 it uses an empty map: `def changeset(user, params \\ %{}) do`

Comment: Note that with Ecto 2.0 it uses an empty map: `def changeset(user, params \\ %{}) do`. See https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.0.2/Ecto.Changeset.html

Comment: Made that prominent in the answer just in case people miss it. Thanks :)

Comment: Any idea why Ecto 2.0 can now default to an empty map?

Comment: With Ecto 2.2.8, passing `:empty` now causes an `Ecto.CastError`. `%{}` works perfectly, though.